# Serilog + Azure - No custom logs appearing in Log Analytics workspace

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, serilog, azure-log-analytics

I'm trying to use Serilog to log to the Log Analytics workspace from an app service, but nothing is being logged there from any of my controllers (which are taking ILogger using DI).

Is there something obvious I'm missing? The workspace shows no custom logs, and the calls to the API return everything they are expected to return.

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // The initial "bootstrap" logger is able to log errors during start-up. It's completely replaced by the
            // logger configured in `UseSerilog()` below, once configuration and dependency-injection have both been
            // set up successfully.
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .CreateBootstrapLogger();

            Log.Information("Starting up!");

            try
            {
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
                Log.Information("Stopped cleanly");
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal(ex, "An unhandled exception occured during bootstrapping");
                return;
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
             .UseSerilog((context, services, configuration) => configuration
                    .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration)
                    .ReadFrom.Services(services)
                    .Enrich.FromLogContext())
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            // Controllers
            services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();

            // Web
            services.AddWebRegistry(Configuration);

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            // Write streamlined request completion events, instead of the more verbose ones from the framework.
            // To use the default framework request logging instead, remove this line and set the "Microsoft"
            // level in appsettings.json to "Information".
            app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.AzureAnalytics" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "Override": {
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR": "Debug",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections": "Debug"
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "AzureAnalytics",
        "Args": {
          "logName": "devlog",
          "authenticationId": "secret",
          "workspaceId": "secret"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId", "WithThreadName", "WithEventType" ]
  },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're missing the package to sink logs from Serilog to Log Analytics:

Add the following packages:

```
Serilog.AspNetCore
Serilog.Sinks.AzureAnalytics
```

then:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .WriteTo.AzureAnalytics(workspaceId: "WORKSPACE ID", 
                                authenticationId: "PRIMARY KEY")
        .CreateLogger();

    CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseSerilog();
```

Comment: Yeah, I'd grabbed the packages already.


However, hard-coding the key and the id seems to make it work, so it looks like I'm not getting the settings correctly.


Rather than play around, I'll just load the settings in by hand I think.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration).Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .CreateLogger();
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddSerilog(logger);
```

This is my config file

```
 "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Sinks.AzureAnalytics" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "SerilogTest": "Debug",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
        "Microsoft": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "../logs/webapi-.log",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} {CorrelationId} {Level:u3} {Username} {Message:lj}{Exception}{NewLine}"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "AzureAnalytics",
        "Args": {
          "logName": "mycustomtablename",
          "authenticationId": "xxxxxxx",
          "workspaceId": "xxxxxx",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} {CorrelationId} {Level:u3} {Username} {Message:lj}{Exception}{NewLine}"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```